# generating np.meshgrid from np.linspace with variable "start"

Tags: python, numpy

let x be in the range (0,1), y in (x,1) and z in (0,1). How can I generate an evenly spaced meshgrid of 3X3X3? Note that the lowerbound/start value of y depends on x. The problem would have been easy if y was in (0,1) instead.

I tried to use x=np.linspace(0,1,3); y=np.linspace(x,1,3); z=np.linspace(0,1,3) and then np.meshgrid(x,y,z), but it doesn't work as intended -- some array is generated but the dimension isn't right.

Comment: Note that the kind of domain that you're trying to get points for is not what is typically represented in a mesh grid. Which points do you expect to be represented in the 3x3x3 meshgrid?

Comment: In anticipation of a possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here, perhaps you could accomplish whatever you're interested in doing by using an nan mask for the elements of the array that aren't in the domain of interest. Could you explain what exactly you're using this meshgrid for?

Comment: To rephrase my first question: the meshgrid with x,y, and z all from (0,1) would correspond to the 27 points (0,0,0),(0,0,0.5),(0,0,1),(0,0.5,0),...,(1,1,1). Are you expecting your meshgrid to correspond to a **subset** of these points, or are you expecting your meshgrid to correspond to a different set of 27 points?

Comment: 2. if by NaN mask, you mean a method to generate a subset of your 27 points, then that's not what I am looking for. for my application, the NaNs would be computationally expensive: my sample size is not 27, but probably 10^7, and the NaN will be 90% of them and for these 90% I'll also have to have the CPU loop over, if I do the masking.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, Ben. 1. my set is not a subset of yours, nor is yours mine. My set: (0,0,0),(0,0.5,0),(0,1,0),(0.5,0.5,0),(0.5,0.75,0),(0.5,1,0),(1,1,0),(0,0,0.5),(0,0.5,0.5),(0,1,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.75,0.5),(0.5,1,0.5),(1,1,0.5),(0,0,1),(0,0.5,1),(0,1,1),(0.5,0.5,1),(0.5,0.75,1),(0.5,1,1),(1,1,1). Note that the second argument is always smaller in value than the 1st. Note also that (0.5,0.75,0) is resulted from dividing x, which is (0.5,1), into three points: 0.5,0.75 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to produce the intended result.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,3)
y = np.linspace(0,1,5)
z = np.linspace(0,1,3)

X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

indices = np.nonzero(X <= Y)

X = X[indices].reshape([3,3,3])
Y = Y[indices].reshape([3,3,3])
Z = Z[indices].reshape([3,3,3])
```

In general, for an n x n x n meshgrid, you should take `y = np.linspace(0,1,2*n - 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for providing this method, Ben. This is probably the NaN masking you were talking about. Not exactly what I was looking for, as my full model will have a few more variables, and determining the mesh size won't be as easy as 2*n-1 for relationships more complex than X<=Y. But this is a legit answer to the verbatim question. Thank you.

Comment: @Kim No, this is not that nan masking that I was talking about. Anyway, I hope it's somehow helpful

Answer (score 0):

sSeems to me that problem is ill-defined.  We need to see that actual numbers that you intend.  And code, even it isn't pretty 'array' stuff.

But lets make x and y, z adds a dimension, but dosn't change anything significant.

```
In [43]: x=np.linspace(0,1,3); y=np.linspace(x,1,3)

In [44]: x
Out[44]: array([0. , 0.5, 1. ])

In [45]: y
Out[45]: 
array([[0.  , 0.5 , 1.  ],
       [0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.  , 1.  ]])
```

`x` is a simple 1d array of 3 elements.

`y` is (3,3), one row for each starting point of `x`.

```
In [46]: np.meshgrid(x,y, indexing='ij')
Out[46]: 
[array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        [1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ]]),
 array([[0.  , 0.5 , 1.  , 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [0.  , 0.5 , 1.  , 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [0.  , 0.5 , 1.  , 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  ]])]
```

This is 2 arrays with shape (3,9).  I have expected meshgrid to raise an error about `y` not being 1d, but looks like it flatted it instead.

Note that all rows of the 1st are identical and all columns of the second are identical.  That's the nature of what `meshgrid` does.

### Ben's

Ben suggests (in my 2d version)

```
In [49]: I,J=np.meshgrid(x,np.linspace(0,1,5), indexing='ij')

In [50]: I,J
Out[50]: 
(array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        [1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ]]),
 array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ],
        [0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ],
        [0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ]]))

In [51]: indices = np.nonzero(I <= J)


In [53]: indices
Out[53]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int64))

In [54]: I[indices]
Out[54]: array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1. ])

In [55]: I[indices].reshape(3,3)
Out[55]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.5, 1. ]])

In [56]: J[indices].reshape(3,3)
Out[56]: 
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.5 ],
       [0.75, 1.  , 0.5 ],
       [0.75, 1.  , 1.  ]])
```

Those values don't make much sense.

Even without the `indices='ij', the result doesn't look more rational

```
In [60]: I[indices].reshape(3,3)
Out[60]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0. , 0.5],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])

In [61]: J[indices].reshape(3,3)
Out[61]: 
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.5 ],
       [0.5 , 0.75, 0.75],
       [1.  , 1.  , 1.  ]])
```

### tril

It sort of sounds like you want an lower or upper triangle. That is one where some values are set to zero (or maybe `nan`?)

```
In [70]: I,J=np.meshgrid(x,x, indexing='ij');I,J
Out[70]: 
(array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        [1. , 1. , 1. ]]),
 array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
        [0. , 0.5, 1. ],
        [0. , 0.5, 1. ]]))

In [71]: np.tril(I)
Out[71]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0. ],
       [1. , 1. , 1. ]])

In [72]: np.tril(J)
Out[72]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
```

Or with nan fill

```
In [77]: I1=np.ones((3,3))*np.nan; I1[indices]=I[indices]; I1
Out[77]: 
array([[0. , nan, nan],
       [0.5, 0.5, nan],
       [1. , 1. , 1. ]])

In [78]: J1=np.ones((3,3))*np.nan; J1[indices]=J[indices]; J1
Out[78]: 
array([[0. , nan, nan],
       [0. , 0.5, nan],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
```

### sparse mesh

`meshgrid` can general `sparse` values, which, with broadcasting, behave exactly the same as the 2d dense

```
In [79]: I,J=np.meshgrid(x,x,sparse=True);I,J
Out[79]: 
(array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ]]),
 array([[0. ],
        [0.5],
        [1. ]]))

In [80]: I+J
Out[80]: 
array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [0.5, 1. , 1.5],
       [1. , 1.5, 2. ]])
```

### your tuples?

From a comment, I deduce that you want 7 tuples (ignoring `z`)

```
((0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0, 1), 
(0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.75), (0.5, 1), 
(1, 1))
```

This is like a upper/lower tri, but you've added the `(0.5, 0.75)`

Or these could be collected  from my [44] and [45], skipping the duplicate 1's in [45]. In any case you have a list (or tuple) of tuples, not a rectangular 'meshgrid'

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your solution, or maybe this is just a comment on Ben's solution? PS, feel free to let me know how you think this problem is ill-defined. The set I list in my comments to the original question might serve as clarification of what the question precisely is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, hpaulj. I indeed intend for a triangle. (0.5, 0.75) is in fact consistent with that. All (x,y) such that x<y would form a triangle, right?

Comment: So this triangle is a set of points that can be plotted.  The focus isn't on a cartesian mesh or what's often called an upper or lower triangle 2 or 3d array with selected points set to 0.

Comment: why isn't this an upper triangle?

Comment: For a 3x3 upper tri, the 2nd index is >= the first.  It's about the index, not vslues.  E.g. (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), or as 2d array `[[1,2,3],[0,5,6],[0,0,9]]`.  Another way to put it, should thev2nd 'row' have 2 values, [.5,1.0], or 3 [.5,.75,1.0]?

Answer (score 0):

After a few day's of research, it seems that the "mesh" related functions in numpy is designed to create (only) square grids. If one needs to generate an odd shaped grid, like a triangle in my case, one can either first generate a square grid, then use indexing to "mute" the ones outside your triangle, or simply write a n-nested loop, where n is the number of variables involved.

Simply put, functions such as meshgrid is NOT designed to generate grids of shapes other than squares.